# How to create a joint column in mysql off of a calculation of other columns

Tags: mysql, database, model, sails.js

I'm trying to creat a 'total column' in my user model. I'm not sure how I can do the calculations. Previously I was doing it on the front end, but that leaves me with very limited sorting options, so I would like to do this on the back end, then append the total row instead.

This is what my model looks like:
module.exports = {

```
autosubscribe: ['destroy'],

attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: 'email',
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        minLength: 6
    },
    status: {
        type: 'string',
        defaultsTo: 'offline',
        required: false
    },
    score: {
        type: 'integer',
        defaultsTo: 0,
        required: false
    },
    totalwins: {
        type: 'integer',
        defaultsTo: 0,
        required: false
    },
    totalgames: {
        type: 'integer',
        defaultsTo: 0,
        required: false
    },
    ip: {
        type: 'string',
        required: false
    }
}
};
```

I tried adding something like

```
scorepct: {
type: 'integer',
defaultsTo: totalwins/totalgames,
required: false
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, are there any ideas on how I can do this from my User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do what you want is to add [lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) to your model. You can make sure that every time you use the default `create` or `update` methods, that property is updated as you wish:

```
attributes: {
    // ...
    scorepct: {
        type: 'integer'
        defaultsTo: 0 // always 0 at creation time
    },
},

afterUpdate: function(attrs, next) {
    var calculatedPct = attrs.totalgames === 0 ? 0 : attrs.totalwins / attrs.totalgames;
    if (calculatedPct === attrs.scorepct) {
        return next();
    }
    User.update(attrs.id, {scorepct: calculatedPct}).exec(function(err, user) {
        // handle the error
        return next();
    });
},
```

This seems like a lot of trouble - why not just calculate the percentage wherever you need it without storing the result in the db? You could arrange to do this automatically at every `.find`, or do this when making api calls for data, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was calculating it on the front end, right where I appended the score, but it made sorting it sort of a pain in the ass. It sounds like that might be the ideal way to to it though, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I see - if you get a huge amount of users, you don't want to get all records, just those with best percentage. In that case, this `afterUpdate` may really be what you need.

Comment: Luckily I only need to pull 32, and I can sort it based on wins

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, maybe this will work

```
scorepct: {
    type: 'integer'
    defaultsTo: function(){ return this.totalwins / this.totalgames }
    required: false
}
```

or

```
scorepct: function(){ return this.totalwins / this.totalgames }
```

Comment: So when I add that, I'm getting `[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'user.scorepct' in 'field list'`
when I try to log into the app. However, if I go and add that column to my table as well, it will result to `null`. :/

Comment: ofc, I forgot `return` ><, edited the comment.
hopefully, that will do the job

Comment: Hmm, still coming back 'null' for me. I think this is on the right track though.